# drush cr behavior

Tags: drush

Is it normal for the site to become unreachable while running `drush cr` or this is something need to be fixed?

I have a site running drupal 9 that is becoming unavailable while running `drush cr` and the nginx webserver throwing 504 timeout error at the same time. if this something wrong I need to troubleshoot, what could cause this while cache rebuild?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) No, that isn't normal. As for what could be wrong, there are dozens if not hundreds of possible causes, you'll need to debug/profile the site in situ. Personally I'd want to fix it, but whether or not _you_ need it to be fixed, depends on whether it's causing you any problems beyond the 504

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the weird thing is no error logs during this happening, the only thing I can see is the 504 errors, does `drush cr` lock the DB? and this could be the issue

Comment: A 504 is not so bad when you clear the cache. You can crash a production server if it is under heavy load.